# C++ template function call seems to prefer the less specialized one

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to simplify some of my earlier JSON serialization by using C++ templates to somewhat reduce boilerplate code. All went fine, until I wanted to serialize types such as lists, since these are templates themselves as well and seem to require partial template specialization, which does not seem to exist for template functions.

Therefore, I applied a neat little trick I found over here:
https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/15/function-templates-partial-specialization-cpp/

```cpp
namespace Support {
// These are in header files
template <typename T>
struct convertType{};

// Specialised template that serialises a list by iterating over its members
template <typename T>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const QList<T> &source, convertType<QList<T>>) {
    QJsonArray result;
    for (auto it = source.cbegin(); it != source.cend(); it++) {
        result.push_back(*it);
    }
    return result;
}

// "Fallback" template that generates an assertion
template <typename T>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const T &source, convertType<T>) {
    // This function should never be called.
    std::string msg = "toJsonValue called with unimplemented type ";
    msg += typeid (T).name();
    Q_ASSERT_X(false, "toJsonValue<T>", msg.c_str()); // Always asserts. 
    return QJsonValue();
}

// Convenience function
template<typename T>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const T &source) {
    return toJsonValue<T>(source, convertType<T>{});
}

// This one is in the CPP file

// Integer
template <>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const int &source, convertType<int>) {
    return QJsonValue(source);
}

} // NS Support
```

When I call this template with an integer as follows:

```cpp
qDebug() << Support::toJsonValue<int>(3713); // if not familiar with Qt, think as qDebug() being the same as std::cout.
```

This outputs "QJsonValue(double, 3713)", as expected.

However, when I try to pass a list as follows:

```cpp
QList<int> foo = {1, 2, 3};
qDebug() << Support::toJsonValue<QList<int>>(foo);
```

The code will take, the in my eyes, least specialized function template, the one that generates an assertion. I have no idea why on earth this is happening, as I would expect that it would take the function template specialized for the `QList`.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Am I perhaps misusing templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea why on earth this is happening, as I would expect that it would take the function template specialised for the QList.

> Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

When you call

```
Support::toJsonValue<QList<int>>(foo);
```

the following "convenience function" matches

```
template<typename T>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const T &source) {
    return toJsonValue<T>(source, convertType<T>{});
}
```

and `T` is `QList<int>`.

So the internal call

```
toJsonValue<T>(source, convertType<T>{})
```

become

```
toJsonValue<QList<int>>(source, convertType<QList<int>>{});
// ........^^^^^^^^^^^^
// ........^^^^^^^^^^^^  here is the problem
```

where you explicitly impose that the `T` type is `QList<int>`

So the call can't matches your `QList` specialization

```
template <typename T>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const QList<T> &source, convertType<QList<T>>)
```

where the template parameter `T` is intended to be `int`, the template argument of `QList`.

Your call can only match the fallback specialization

```
template <typename T>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const T &source, convertType<T>)
```

Suggestion: lets works the template deduction. I mean: do not explicit the template argument in the internal call

```
template<typename T>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const T &source) {
    return toJsonValue(source, convertType<T>{}); 
} // ......^^^^^^^^^^^
  // ......^^^^^^^^^^^ no more "<T>" after toJsonValue
```

so both the two-argument `toJsonValue()` function match (the `Qlist` version with `T` that is deduced as `int` and the fallback version with `T` that is deduced as `QList<int>`) but the more specialized (the `QList` version) should be selected.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Within the for loop in the QList overloop in my question, I used mistakenly `result.push_back(*it);`, but that also should be `result.push_back(toJsonValue(*it, convertType<T>{}));` and not `result.push_back(toJsonValue<T>(*it, convertType<T>{}));` it seems. Many thanks for your detailed answer, I was pulling my hair out over this problem for several hours and it just didn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Does this two are equivalent? It seems like you create a overload instead of a partial specialization.

```
// Integer
template <>
QJsonValue toJsonValue(const int &source, convertType<int>) {
    return QJsonValue(source);
}
```

```
// Integer
template <>
QJsonValue<int> toJsonValue(const int &source, convertType<int>) {
    return QJsonValue(source);
}
```

Comment: [QJsonValue](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/qjsonvalue.html) is not a template class, as far as I am aware of, so adding template parameters to QJsonValue<int> should not work, right?

Comment: Sorry, I was saying `QJsonValue toJsonValue<int>(const int &source, convertType<int>) `. But I think it was in your Convenience function, T will be fixed to `QList<int>` instead of `int`, so it can't match the specialized one. Try `toJsonValue(source, convertType<T>{})`.